# Adding Field to Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to make this code to work in access to simply add a new field column to a table called "Collections" but it seems that Access does nothing:

```
Sub CreateCalculatedField()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
' get the database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

' create the table
Set tdf = dbs.CreateTableDef("Collections")

' create the fields: first name, last name

tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField("Running Total", dbText, 20)

Cleanup:
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c5a749d-a479-4486-abf8-e1c9d49ef057/adding-a-table-column-using-vba-in-access?forum=isvvba

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to tell dbs that you want to create table.

Dbs.TableDefs.Append tdf